# Mono for Android error: GetMethodID: method not found: Landroid/widget/EditText;.monodroidAddReference:(Ljava/lang/Object;)

Tags: android, mono, android-widget, xamarin.android

I'm nearing completion of my Mono for Android app.  I have an Activity that has a ListView which uses a layout to display a few rows of information, nothing major.  It then shows a pretty complex Activity (three tabs, quite a few controls).

I can tap an item in the list and it shows the activity, all is fine.  About every 3-4 views I get the error below:

```
07-10 13:12:01.824  4635  4635 D dalvikvm: GetMethodID: method not found: Landroid/widget/EditText;.monodroidAddReference:(Ljava/lang/Object;)V
```

I can't seem to locate the source of this error.  I do have a few custom controls (complex controls, i.e. combined edittext, buttons, etc. for reusability) but I've tried tearing things down with no luck.

If anyone can help track down the source of this error I'd greatly appreciate it.  I'm about a week from release.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to ignore the GetMethodID error; checking for the `monodroidAddReference()` method is part of the GC mechanism, and platform-supplied types (like android.widget.EditText) aren't expected to provide a `monodroidAddReference()` method.

Is there any other relevant `adb` output?

Comment: Thanks for the reply, no, there's no other relevant information that I could see.  I just proceeded with development, the app should release this week.  Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to assume this is either a bug that won't be fixed as Mono for Android has been abandoned or it's a false positive in the logcat.  I have been unable to resolve this so I will ignore it and proceed.